# Angular dropdown button to left side of it

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I have a little problem with a dropdown button. I am trying to adjust my website to mobile. What I want is to have a button that will dropdown to left-hand side of it. Her is my html code;

```
<!-- A div element for the button that will contain the nav-bar buttons -->
<div style="position: absolute; ; right: 0px; margin-top: 40px;" ngbDropdown class="btn-group dropleft">
    <button class="btn adjustbtn dropdown-toggle" style="width: auto; height: 20px;" ngbDropdownToggle></button>
    <div ngbDropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu">
        <button ngbDropdownItem>All Sports</button>
        <button ngbDropdownItem>Basketball</button>
        <button ngbDropdownItem>Football</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

But the problem is this button is still dropping down to the right-hand side of it, althoug the arrow at my dropdown button points to left. How can I fix this?

Comment: Try adding the class _dropdown-menu-left_ .. For more info visit https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/dropdown/api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
<div style="position: absolute; left:auto !important; right: 0 !important; margin-top: 40px;" ngbDropdown class="btn-group dropleft">
    <button class="btn adjustbtn dropdown-toggle" style="width: auto; height: 20px;" ngbDropdownToggle></button>
    <div ngbDropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu">
        <button ngbDropdownItem>All Sports</button>
        <button ngbDropdownItem>Basketball</button>
        <button ngbDropdownItem>Football</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are using ng-bootstrap dropdown.

If yes, you should use its class `dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right`.

```
<div style="position: absolute; ; right: 0px; margin-top: 40px;" ngbDropdown class="btn-group dropleft">
    <button class="btn adjustbtn dropdown-toggle" style="width: auto; height: 20px;" ngbDropdownToggle></button>
    <div ngbDropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
        <button ngbDropdownItem>All Sports</button>
        <button ngbDropdownItem>Basketball</button>
        <button ngbDropdownItem>Football</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Sample: [dropdown examples](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mcgxdv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdropdown-navbar.html)